# Opencart error Message box when i select payment in step 5

Tags: opencart

There is a strange message called 'error' in message box after giving continue in step 5. I am trying to confirm order but it replied a message box just with 'error' text. It doesn't move to step 6 (confirm order). I also check with error log there is no updates there. If anybody know what it is, please reply......

Comment: I turned off js error script but it is not moving to step-6. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I don't know exactly but i think it may be javascript problem. I'm using opencart 1.5.6.1.

Comment: Didn't you face the problem before?